# Achieve same blur used in Find My Friends app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, blur

[image]

Above is the effect I want to achieve. A subtle blur can be seen through the transparency of the table view. My attempt

Currently my app table view has a background opacity of 80% which gives a similar effect, but no where near as nice as the effect in the Apple Find My Friends app. I understand the effect is very subtle, but that is what I am looking to achieve.

What is the best way to go about blurring the map behind the table view that will work on iOS 7 and iOS 8?

Though my app is written in Swift, I can just about get by with Objective C answers (though I'd prefer Swift). Any ideas?

Comment: check out [FXBlurView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXBlurView)

Comment: @NewEngland Cheers, would you say that's the most widely supported library for blurring a view?

Comment: Not sure. Its pretty popular though

Answer (score 0):

The best way to add blur in iOS 8 is by using the class UIVisualEffectView. It is a native class that comes with UIKit, which means that this will most likely come closest to the effect you are looking for.

I don't know how you are displaying your map, so I can't tell you the exact way to do it. For a UIImageView it would work like this:

```
var visualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .Light)) as UIVisualEffectView

visualEffectView.frame = imageView.bounds

imageView.addSubview(visualEffectView)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm looking for a solution that works in iOS 7 as well as iOS 8